# Align border with text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys for some reason i cant seem to allign my border i have on my navbar with my text at all : You can see in the fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38348/)

Every time i try and `margin-top` the border it moves everything down. The navbar text it self is in the right place on my webpage, i just want to move the actual border lines down to align with the position of the text

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6D6D6D;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 28px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.navbar-nav>li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  margin-top: 19px;
  margin-right: 43px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #FFC600;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#myNavbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand"><img alt="" src="Images/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please correct the below CSS Class it looks better, please let me know if you have any issues with this fix.

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `a`

```
.navbar-nav>li a { // ...
.navbar-nav>li:last-child a { // ...
```

Remove padding, just leave it as it was before.
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r7L8b68u/)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you had a padding on the `.navbar-nav>li` which was causing this issue.

Here's the updated CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #6D6D6D;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: 300;
}



.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    padding-top: 9px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
      border-right: 1px solid white;
    height: 30px;
    text-align:center;
}

.navbar-nav>li:last-child{
   border: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}


.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 19px;
    margin-right: 43px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    background-color: #FFC600;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 200ms linear;
    transition: background-color 200ms linear;
}
```

And a working link: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/38351/